# Magento - Cannot get cart info into an external page

Tags: magento

I have magento installed in a folder called store. The min site is installed above that at the root of the hosting.

I have followed many ideas on how to get the cart to display on external pages, but I cannot seem to get any info passed from magento.

```
<?
$mageFilename = 'store/app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;

umask(0);
Mage::app();

/* Init User Session */
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));

if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
echo'logged in <br />';
/* do something if logged in */
} else {
echo'not logged in<br />';
/* do something else if not logged in */
}

/* Magento uses different sessions for 'frontend' and 'adminhtml' */
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));

$cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getItemsCount();

echo 'cart items count: ' . $cart;
?>
```

I have this code at present to call the number of items in the cart, and also state whether the user is logged in or not. But nothing seems to get passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must run this from a Magento Controller.

Magento is an incredibly powerful, advanced, professional PHP platform. It *is* one of the most advanced PHP MVC frameworks out there. If you're trying to build a PHP site that has a Magento store in it, why wouldn't you use Magento to build the whole site? Are you using a better platform?

Comment: I have my own content management system for the other parts of the site. But am using magento for the store side of things. I want to bring the cart info out of magento and display it on the other bits of the site